# SQL meta table help (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables ("news", "category" and as a join table "meta"). I'm just trying to filter news that contains `category_id` which is provided as filter parameter. I tried the query below (and similar) but it returning all news from news table.

So how to filter these news by `meta_id (category_id)`?

Thanks a lot!

```
// category table
category_id | category_name
---------------------------
55          | Sport
56          | Politics

// meta table
meta_id | meta_type | rel_id | rel_type
---------------------------------------
55      | category  | 78345  | news
56      | category  | 91278  | news

Notes:
rel_id (in meta table)  = id (in news table) // i don't need it in this case
meta_id (in meta table) = category_id (in category table)
```

SQL:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM `news` n
LEFT JOIN `metas` m ON m.meta_type='category'
    WHERE m.meta_id=55 AND n.status=1
GROUP BY n.id
ORDER BY n.id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: What is the structure of your `news` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is to link `metas` to `news`.  If I read your question correctly, the link field is `m.rel_id = n.id`.  The following example query should filter for category 55:

```
select  *
from    metas m
join    news n
on      m.rel_id = n.id
where   m.meta_type = 'category'
        and m.meta_id = 55
        and n.status = 1
order by
        n.id desc
limit   0, 10
```

N.B. Not sure why you have a `group by` in your query.  It's certainly not required to filter for category!

Comment: Thanks for answer!

`group by` for: `where` getting many parameters on list (search) page and needs using group by, but here is just "filter_by_category" condition which doesn't need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a condition in your `ON` clause.

```
SELECT n.*
FROM `news` n
LEFT JOIN `metas` m ON m.meta_type='category' AND m.meta_id = n.category_id
    WHERE m.meta_id=55 AND n.status=1
GROUP BY n.id
ORDER BY n.id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: But there is no `n.category_id`. Also I tried `ON m.meta_type='category' AND m.meta_id=2` but useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.*
FROM `news` n
LEFT outer JOIN `metas` m ON m.meta_id = n.category_id
    WHERE m.meta_id=55 AND n.status=1 and m.meta_type='category'
GROUP BY n.id
ORDER BY n.id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Also I tried this too bu does not work and there is no `n.category_id`, new category kept by `rel_id` and i dont need it. I am just trying to list news by `category_id` (so `meta_id`).